# I am writing automation script on website and while running script from python I am getting this error "Website_link is not a supported browser."

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, testautomationfx

Here is the code that I am using

Resource file code

```
*** Settings ***

Library  SeleniumLibrary

Variables       ../PageObject/inspectpath.py

*** Keywords ***

open my browser

    [Arguments]    ${siteurl}   ${browser}
    open browser    ${siteurl}   ${browser}
    maximize browser window
```

Testcase file

```
*** Settings ***

Library    SeleniumLibrary

Resource   ../Resources/OCKeywords.robot


*** Variables ***

${browser}      chrome

${siteurl}     http://automationpractice.com/index.php



*** Test Cases ***

Register

    open my browser     ${browser}      ${siteurl}
```

Comment: Can you share your actual code? What you've written isn't clear.

Comment: Your `open my browser` has arguments `${siteurl}` `${browser}`
But you are passing in your test file `${browser}` `${siteurl}`. It should be `${siteurl}` `${browser}`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to your `open my browser` keyword is the site url, and the second is the name of the browser. That is because you defined the arguments like this:

```
[Arguments]    ${siteurl}   ${browser}
```

However, when you call it you are sending the arguments in reverse order here:

```
open my browser     ${browser}      ${siteurl}
```

The solution is to pass the arguments in the correct order:

```
open my browser     ${siteurl}  ${browser}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Bryan Oakley I also compared my old project file with this but didn't recognize this small mistake.